# Is there a way to enable support of optional chaining operators in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, ecmascript-next

I work on a project where we use [optional chaining operator](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/7.0/packages/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining) (aka Elvis operator):

```
const baz = new obj?.foo?.bar?.baz()
```

Is it a way to make WebStorm understand it?

P.S. It's a part of `stage-1` proposals: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Comment: It has been released. You can close this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Finally typescript version **`3.7`** supports **`optional chaining.`** For webstorm to support it you need to update it to the latest version. It would work as expected.

Typescript - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Webstorm Release notes - https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/10/webstorm-2019-2-4/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an issue about this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27592. Seems like it's resolved so we can wait for the feature in next build.